# Wordpress export not importing all data

Tags: wordpress

Exported my staging site to an xml, imported that xml to the live site but not everything has imported, below is the image of the staging site, and then the live site

https://i.stack.imgur.com/IAl85.jpg

as you can see they look very different, any ideas? both sites are set to public.

Comment: I recommend using a plugin to migrate, the one I use is "shipper" by WPMUDev, it is however a expensive license. Other then that I would recommend you to check if your theme settings has an option to export as it looks like that is what's potentially missing, another thing you could check is if it has set your homepage correctly

Answer (score 1):

Wordpress built-in exports are not meant to export all your data. They just export settings and such.

Unfortunately, the way to sync dev / stage / prod in wordpress rely either on plugins (like All-in-one WP migration), or manual steps :

- Sync all your database (beware of the URL in wp-config)
- Sync all your files via FTP or else (including themes and others)
- Sync your settings as you did

I won't be more explicit, there's plenty of documentation on the web on this exact topic!